# What is the purpose of making the question a link which redirects back to the same question

Tags: bug

Reproduce:

1. Go to [Why would you store an enum in DB?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305148/why-would-you-store-an-enum-in-db)
2. Click on the title of the question
3. The browser is redirected to the same question.

Whenever I try copying the text of the question I accidentally click on it and the whole page is reloaded.

I have checked this behaviour in stackoverflow and softwareengineering.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47653/why-does-the-question-title-link-to-itself-on-the-answer-page